# How to activate different functions if you are at certain part of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make two functions, "functionattoppage" and "functionat1000pxpage". I want to make the function "functionattoppage" activate when the user is at the top of a webpage and "functionat1000pxpage" activate when the user is down about 1000px from the top of the page, is this possible?

Here is the only thing I could come up with:

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 1000 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1000) {
      document.body.classList.add("body.changed");
  }
  
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      document.body.classList.remove("body.changed");
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Please look at the JavaScript section, it is what my best guess would be on how to make this work</h1>
```

Sorry if I didn't explain this very well, I don't have much time right now. If you need more information please ask me.

Comment: Does it have to be at ~1000px? Could you create an element on the page and call a function once it is rendered? If so, you could simply use jquery to do something like ```if($('#element').is(':visible')){}```

Comment: That would work perfectly in theory! I will try it now.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, would you mind posting a more in-depth answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After console logging `document.body.scrollTop`in the fiddle came out to be zero. Plus your conditions are bound to fail because when scrollTop > 1000 then it is > 0 too.

you should either make it a else or move the >0 condition to the first

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);

  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[1].classList.add("changed");
  }
  else{
    document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[1].classList.remove("changed");
  }

}
```

```css
.changed {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<h1>Please look at the JavaScript section, it is what my best guess would be on how to make this work</h1>
<div style="height: 400px;background: grey;"></div>
<h1>Please look at the JavaScript section, it is what my best guess would be on how to make this work</h1>
<div style="height: 400px;background: grey;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to hide a class when the scroll position for the window is within 0 and 1000 pixels yes? The a conditional that will check if the scrollY position of the window, `window.scrollY` is greater than 0, but less than 1000, add the class else remove the class.

```js
window.onscroll = () => {
  scrollFunction()
}

const scrollFunction = () => {
  window.scrollY > 0 && window.scrollY < 1000 ?
    document.body.classList.add("changed") :
    document.body.classList.remove("changed")
  document.getElementById("scroll_position").textContent = window.scrollY;
}
```

```css
#scroll_position {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100px;
}

#cont {
  height: 3000px;
}

#cont h1 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.changed {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p id="scroll_position"></p>
<div id="cont">
  <h1>Please look at the JavaScript section, it is what my best guess would be on how to make this work</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div as your marker. And when it is >= 0 execute one function and when it gets to -1000px execute another. Use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get an elements coordinates.

HTML

```
<div id=“marker1”></div>
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener( "scroll", function(){
  let marker1 = document.getElementById("marker1").getBoundingClientRect();

  if (marker1.top >= 0) atTop(); 
  if (marker1.top <= -1000) at1000px();
})
function atTop() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
function at1000px() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Be aware the `atTop` won’t execute until you start scrolling because of the type of event listener. If you want it executed on load also then you’ll need to add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through sensing the scroll event as you are doing, but it's quite overheady.

Instead you could use an IntersectionObserver on a couple of elements, This will tell you when they come into and go out of the viewport and you don't have to worry about any intermediate scrolling.

If you already have elements that you want to sense in those positions you could sense those going into and out of the viewport. If not you can 'plant' a couple of 1px divs at the top and at 1000px and sense them coming in and out.

This snippet just logs the comings and goings to the console but of course you put whatever code you want in their place.

```js
function callback (entries) {
  for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    if (entries[i].isIntersecting) {console.log(entries[i].target.classList + ' is in the viewport'); }
    else {console.log(entries[i].target.classList + ' is not in the viewport'); }
  }
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
const sensors = document.querySelectorAll('.sensor');

for (let i = 0; i < sensors.length; i++) {
  observer.observe(sensors[i]);
}
```

```css
.talldiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue, orange, green, purple, cyan); /*just so we notice scrolling */
}
.sensor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: var(--top);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: transparent;
}
.sensetop {
  --top: 0px;
}
.sense1000px {
  --top: 999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sensor sensetop"></div>
<div class="sensor sense1000px"></div>
<div class="talldiv"></div>
```